# IntelliJ with gradle not loading native libraries

Tags: java, gradle, intellij-idea, processing

I'm not a Java developer but I'm using Processing for some personal projects and to expand my knowledge base. I recently moved my project to IntelliJ because the Processing IDE was just too clunky. I was able to get all the libraries I need added to intelliJ using jar files and everything worked great. However, I'm needing to use a library that is only available using gradle and I figured this would be a good time to move all my libraries over.

This is working great for the most part. I have all my libraries added as gradle dependencies and the project builds. However, I'm trying to add a piece to the project using the processing video library which requires native windows library `.dll` files and I am hitting a wall trying to get them imported.

I've added them through the project structure > Libraries editor but I'm still hitting the compiler error

here's the gist full error dump below

`java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: can't load library gio-2.0 (gio-2.0|libgio-2.0|libgio-2.0-0) with -Djna.library.path=null. Last error:java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'gio-2.0': Native library (win32-x86-64/gio-2.0.dll) not found in resource path`

I'm wondering if the -Djna.library.path=null is a clue here?

Is there a trick to using the video library? https://search.maven.org/artifact/org.processing/video/3.3.7/jar

I'm trying to import this folder that I've pulled out of the processing directory. This method worked when running this program by just manually importing libraries into IntelliJ.

Here's the whole shebang...

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: can't load library gio-2.0 (gio-2.0|libgio-2.0|libgio-2.0-0) with -Djna.library.path=null. Last error:java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Unable to load library 'gio-2.0': Native library (win32-x86-64/gio-2.0.dll) not found in resource path (C:\Users\myusr\Documents\MusicVisualizerGradle\MusicVisualizer\build\classes\java\main;C:\Users\myusr\Documents\MusicVisualizerGradle\MusicVisualizer\build\resources\main;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\ddf.minim\ddf.minim\2.2.0\9710b785579b681fdb83d5bda0133f97d68750dc\ddf.minim-2.2.0.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.processing\video\3.3.7\7e51ff94d1e19fbd801d01e979f6a4c6b1be4234\video-3.3.7.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.github.cdimascio\dotenv-java\2.2.4\e02c0ec8966439b93e64b9fc8b0c5eb1dea96afb\dotenv-java-2.2.4.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.json\json\20220320\6df2c050972619466f6dcef7654ef9bcc01dfd0\json-20220320.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.github.twitch4j\twitch4j\1.10.0\3e29972edee84db26a445b4f24ace7d45e66cb15\twitch4j-1.10.0.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.clojure\clojure\1.5.1\e7e53da8bc4ac41fca95ccfacf84f9469dd3147f\clojure-1.5.1.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.clojars.automata\jl\1.0.0\2020d545657508bd82beab00359dcc50996b875e\jl-1.0.0.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.clojars.automata\mp3spi\1.9.4\beccb1a3e766d0bd782a174d7cca0a47ba3b89d8\mp3spi-1.9.4.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.clojars.automata\tritonus-aos\1.0.0\f823b89f637b65ced54a77eb7cf00cf62e68147e\tritonus-aos-1.0.0.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.clojars.automata\tritonus-share\1.0.0\e5646da280be9f1e07301b35339a376ac640df9f\tritonus-share-1.0.0.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.processing\core\3.3.7\6e0983fb0841935eaa3386395e712d609856ab90\core-3.3.7.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.googlecode.gstreamer-java\gstreamer-java\1.5\b45f34c51c7b664b133d3e86628d120369b3f54c\gstreamer-java-1.5.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\net.java.dev.jna\jna\4.0.0\9b3a11c613ec3fd3440af4103b12c3de82d38b6e\jna-4.0.0.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.github.twitch4j\twitch4j-chat\1.10.0\c51a920d7cd78c5bcfe1a14caecf7181170133ce\twitch4j-chat-1.10.0.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.github.twitch4j\twitch4j-extensions\1.10.0\d73081f55b5efda60dabfbf3e50f99cb2e28358c\twitch4j-extensions-1.10.0.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.github.twitch4j\twitch4j-helix\1.10.0\41d19a9c241c79c15a0c5be504ea30657b3c5d2e\twitch4j-helix-1.10.0.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.github.twitch4j\twitch4j-pubsub\1.10.0\4b2b254fcbd5a8029fce0ae20f4dcc9c23d16f09\twitch4j-pubsub-1.10.0.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.github.twitch4j\twitch4j-eventsub-common\1.10.0\8438b453e9ea6e277772c388e9bb6b62be64f0f9\twitch4j-eventsub-common-1.10.0.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.github.twitch4j\twitch4j-graphql\1.10.0\752437578db5b9c6ae272ac4ff8ed31af2114564\twitch4j-graphql-1.10.0.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.github.twitch4j\twitch4j-kraken\1.10.0\e8ee78db9fb7708e41cb59cab8f7513ebe6cb641\twitch4j-kraken-1.10.0.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.github.twitch4j\twitch4j-messaginginterface\1.10.0\f17321a5069d15e5b0ca11479825c0821cb51a79\twitch4j-messaginginterface-1.10.0.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.github.twitch4j\twitch4j-common\1.10.0\c0bd06d1ae3810eb2635a3860d7353bd2c40dad1\twitch4j-common-1.10.0.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.github.twitch4j\twitch4j-auth\1.10.0\1ad522afa4a0b902c4e2a9d265762c3046463f21\twitch4j-auth-1.10.0.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.github.twitch4j\twitch4j-client-websocket\1.10.0\3848ae5d9b3c9b933c4f816ee6403ff4a9ea6c6\twitch4j-client-websocket-1.10.0.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.github.twitch4j\twitch4j-util\1.10.0\815656d9e50b9e861ec2ab3f0ddffc45342d830c\twitch4j-util-1.10.0.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.github.philippheuer.credentialmanager\credentialmanager\0.1.2\fef97b49c43d902baca970753837900fdeeace3f\credentialmanager-0.1.2.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.github.openfeign\feign-okhttp\11.8\48e64e62cee485b47ea7778a6f0d8df9106b68a6\feign-okhttp-11.8.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.apollographql.apollo\apollo-runtime\2.5.11\ccd174d4986eb7ecbcea60be4e01a57b4c1917f4\apollo-runtime-2.5.11.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.squareup.okhttp3\okhttp\4.9.3\b0b14b3d12980912723fb8b66afb48dcda742fcb\okhttp-4.9.3.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.apollographql.apollo\apollo-http-cache-api\2.5.11\6f0eaab2ae6900f9902aa36362c920766db16fab\apollo-http-cache-api-2.5.11.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.apollographql.apollo\apollo-normalized-cache-jvm\2.5.11\4502c6d1e92536bdf84d8b9b4fc0f9013f8efb08\apollo-normalized-cache-jvm-2.5.11.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.apollographql.apollo\apollo-normalized-cache-api-jvm\2.5.11\11f424049975c093fce0f370c17c152fb0fcec8b\apollo-normalized-cache-api-jvm-2.5.11.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.apollographql.apollo\apollo-api-jvm\2.5.11\35ccc107999aec6dde1ecd0a774a7e59f9edf34d\apollo-api-jvm-2.5.11.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib-jdk8\1.5.0\65fbc439df2e4aad1f3769762d54534f1b564090\kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.5.0.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib-jdk7\1.5.0\f61904618ea7be07a66e0545ffe8dc2c70a19b77\kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.5.0.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.squareup.okio\okio\2.9.0\dcc813b08ce5933f8bdfd1dfbab4ad4bd170e7a\okio-jvm-2.9.0.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.benasher44\uuid-jvm\0.2.0\4f45ddff7626ca3342c80897afa235cdbf540ba2\uuid-jvm-0.2.0.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib\1.5.0\29dae2501ca094416d15af0e21470cb634780444\kotlin-stdlib-1.5.0.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains\annotations\23.0.0\8cc20c07506ec18e0834947b84a864bfc094484e\annotations-23.0.0.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.github.ben-manes.caffeine\caffeine\2.9.3\b162491f768824d21487551873f9b3b374a7fe19\caffeine-2.9.3.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.github.openfeign\feign-hystrix\11.8\19c860f1c5748d87a718d2cfcfb9a3d640bacded\feign-hystrix-11.8.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.netflix.hystrix\hystrix-core\1.5.18\e1a7ed48e1a60abbb08027a46189afb04c05b04f\hystrix-core-1.5.18.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.netflix.archaius\archaius-core\0.4.1\69e956ddf4543c989461352a214f32a014abd64a\archaius-core-0.4.1.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\commons-configuration\commons-configuration\1.10\2b36e4adfb66d966c5aef2d73deb6be716389dc9\commons-configuration-1.10.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.github.vladimir-bukhtoyarov\bucket4j-core\7.5.0\6c2ab325bffa42318df298cd450ee60097163c37\bucket4j-core-7.5.0.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.github.philippheuer.events4j\events4j-core\0.10.0\2929d4cea91777d4c4754b8192e69266039efd95\events4j-core-0.10.0.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.github.philippheuer.events4j\events4j-handler-simple\0.10.0\a2a50f59674d64231e082050ad600b8bc3132669\events4j-handler-simple-0.10.0.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.github.openfeign\feign-slf4j\11.8\f5fa5b7c70029f40e1b4f9ba197f48ad0bd51c3a\feign-slf4j-11.8.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.github.openfeign\feign-jackson\11.8\e72fb0a6283a3c870635f7025ddaf9c7dcb56181\feign-jackson-11.8.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.neovisionaries\nv-websocket-client\2.14\1b66d37914b232cef45e56ec8c01907620de9e3a\nv-websocket-client-2.14.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\commons-io\commons-io\2.11.0\a2503f302b11ebde7ebc3df41daebe0e4eea3689\commons-io-2.11.0.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.apache.commons\commons-lang3\3.12.0\c6842c86792ff03b9f1d1fe2aab8dc23aa6c6f0e\commons-lang3-3.12.0.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.github.philippheuer.events4j\events4j-api\0.10.0\59a77ccf21b54e414c50a6cd2689ed47ff716369\events4j-api-0.10.0.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.slf4j\slf4j-api\1.7.36\6c62681a2f655b49963a5983b8b0950a6120ae14\slf4j-api-1.7.36.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype\jackson-datatype-jsr310\2.13.2\cddd9380efd4b81ea01e98be8fbdc9765a81793b\jackson-datatype-jsr310-2.13.2.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-databind\2.13.2\926e48c451166a291f1ce6c6276d9abbefa7c00f\jackson-databind-2.13.2.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-annotations\2.13.2\ec18851f1976d5b810ae1a5fcc32520d2d38f77a\jackson-annotations-2.13.2.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.fasterxml.jackson.core\jackson-core\2.13.2\a6a0e0620d51833feffc67bccb51937b2345763\jackson-core-2.13.2.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jogamp.gluegen\gluegen-rt-main\2.3.2\6a86a9ce357c085e3052efcf639447f9957b82b8\gluegen-rt-main-2.3.2.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jogamp.jogl\jogl\2.3.2\99e731771477fe0e142a65d77f9398b83755ec07\jogl-2.3.2.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jogamp.jogl\jogl-all-main\2.3.2\6a86a9ce357c085e3052efcf639447f9957b82b8\jogl-all-main-2.3.2.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jogamp.jogl\newt-main\2.3.2\6a86a9ce357c085e3052efcf639447f9957b82b8\newt-main-2.3.2.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jogamp.jogl\nativewindow-main\2.3.2\6a86a9ce357c085e3052efcf639447f9957b82b8\nativewindow-main-2.3.2.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\net.java.dev.jna\platform\3.4.0\e3f70017be8100d3d6923f50b3d2ee17714e9c13\platform-3.4.0.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.apple\AppleJavaExtensions\1.4\c586cd0b44cae8c0239a977277f99d08d751a482\AppleJavaExtensions-1.4.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.checkerframework\checker-qual\3.19.0\838b42bb6f7f73315167b359d24649845cef1c48\checker-qual-3.19.0.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.errorprone\error_prone_annotations\2.10.0\9bc20b94d3ac42489cf6ce1e42509c86f6f861a1\error_prone_annotations-2.10.0.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\commons-lang\commons-lang\2.6\ce1edb914c94ebc388f086c6827e8bdeec71ac2\commons-lang-2.6.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\commons-logging\commons-logging\1.1.1\5043bfebc3db072ed80fbd362e7caf00e885d8ae\commons-logging-1.1.1.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.github.openfeign\feign-core\11.8\9eab16a2ec5286808afde890dbf3c533ff517fbe\feign-core-11.8.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\io.reactivex\rxjava\1.2.0\42bfaf64c94f3848ebf5cf1c2ea4ec9d1b3ac6c8\rxjava-1.2.0.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.hdrhistogram\HdrHistogram\2.1.9\e4631ce165eb400edecfa32e03d3f1be53dee754\HdrHistogram-2.1.9.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jogamp.gluegen\gluegen-rt\2.3.2\edc35ccfc13d4a4ad02c50d580874c18bf48bbef\gluegen-rt-2.3.2.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jogamp.gluegen\gluegen-rt\2.3.2\4c104c7aef98cda5c404eacb96b1a4e04fe0dd68\gluegen-rt-2.3.2-natives-android-aarch64.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jogamp.gluegen\gluegen-rt\2.3.2\2130295b94ef5c19f85fb4ba6107ca193e987858\gluegen-rt-2.3.2-natives-android-armv6.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jogamp.gluegen\gluegen-rt\2.3.2\477a6bc4f9256d8c9935b75d55e2b7b01314440b\gluegen-rt-2.3.2-natives-linux-amd64.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jogamp.gluegen\gluegen-rt\2.3.2\c55cd566d98d4fcd004b9aaa2c502c8c2dcec192\gluegen-rt-2.3.2-natives-linux-armv6.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jogamp.gluegen\gluegen-rt\2.3.2\f6d3587b061d7ae6e68932fc62317e3500d2112d\gluegen-rt-2.3.2-natives-linux-armv6hf.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jogamp.gluegen\gluegen-rt\2.3.2\da68aff010edd35a9ee89b1801dce6e284c7e673\gluegen-rt-2.3.2-natives-linux-i586.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jogamp.gluegen\gluegen-rt\2.3.2\7227ae9e480354909d80f4df92b30bbb965387be\gluegen-rt-2.3.2-natives-macosx-universal.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jogamp.gluegen\gluegen-rt\2.3.2\9a23cd22c59e3f04082e7589e850b79c9e696dc4\gluegen-rt-2.3.2-natives-solaris-amd64.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jogamp.gluegen\gluegen-rt\2.3.2\a5d9ee96c7a365055fba41e30f9a10f42a3c1a3e\gluegen-rt-2.3.2-natives-solaris-i586.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jogamp.gluegen\gluegen-rt\2.3.2\85213c97a5a50d8dd37de4c35ef32cd4b0ac2ef0\gluegen-rt-2.3.2-natives-windows-amd64.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jogamp.gluegen\gluegen-rt\2.3.2\f9b848384a343f39f454e59cead435c2c0cbf542\gluegen-rt-2.3.2-natives-windows-i586.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jogamp.jogl\jogl-all\2.3.2\99e0f64bb8882f054825ae4a8a527a17b544a0b5\jogl-all-2.3.2.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jogamp.jogl\jogl-all\2.3.2\166147f43cf7419c4d858cd31f4b5922d6d10c81\jogl-all-2.3.2-natives-android-aarch64.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jogamp.jogl\jogl-all\2.3.2\ab2c18b8a1327255cc354c19c720807d262baa75\jogl-all-2.3.2-natives-android-armv6.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jogamp.jogl\jogl-all\2.3.2\ffd1c6bd5f6fb088df6cad25e25721eb55ad2228\jogl-all-2.3.2-natives-linux-amd64.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jogamp.jogl\jogl-all\2.3.2\6d14f46336be9e2dc5f85d5df17490cee5d09a90\jogl-all-2.3.2-natives-linux-armv6.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jogamp.jogl\jogl-all\2.3.2\2c434c560dbd821b0ed569e44d3d441727491dac\jogl-all-2.3.2-natives-linux-armv6hf.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jogamp.jogl\jogl-all\2.3.2\59b7a336c0ee54161e33662d2ca8ac9d8f6c476d\jogl-all-2.3.2-natives-linux-i586.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jogamp.jogl\jogl-all\2.3.2\2da2215dbe1091c54cb83cf2484f8a54a4d0cf7a\jogl-all-2.3.2-natives-macosx-universal.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jogamp.jogl\jogl-all\2.3.2\bde11ff064181af9c307180d8f3f1744b7bdc11d\jogl-all-2.3.2-natives-solaris-amd64.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jogamp.jogl\jogl-all\2.3.2\94d1ed501fe53b7f75eab0f712f39802390d0f5b\jogl-all-2.3.2-natives-solaris-i586.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jogamp.jogl\jogl-all\2.3.2\becd519b1f741176561d93645abd90971ca0dca0\jogl-all-2.3.2-natives-windows-amd64.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jogamp.jogl\jogl-all\2.3.2\5db8db5eca6b4445db6cd14f68938736630ae976\jogl-all-2.3.2-natives-windows-i586.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jogamp.jogl\newt\2.3.2\2f0d759de0a7d61be4cba251b573b98bcef608d8\newt-2.3.2.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jogamp.jogl\newt\2.3.2\5268c4c933bdcc1188e01dc3d0eb218bda277db3\newt-2.3.2-event.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jogamp.jogl\newt\2.3.2\2b7005b3693c301ba81c00a50dae413427f85791\newt-2.3.2-ogl.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jogamp.jogl\newt\2.3.2\a43e9001b3651548ceac27061001a0d0054d2908\newt-2.3.2-driver-android.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jogamp.jogl\newt\2.3.2\4b4af96e706899860846f04d2933e859234326ca\newt-2.3.2-driver-bcm-old.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jogamp.jogl\newt\2.3.2\4c53748c34d6d2c30908ba3007816ca85f0e0791\newt-2.3.2-driver-bcm-vc.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jogamp.jogl\newt\2.3.2\edb56dfa3e4ecdf08c85e6ad78d3a187f7a753c8\newt-2.3.2-driver-intelgdl.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jogamp.jogl\newt\2.3.2\14da99081d9289fa556fc6aab4589b229197a3e4\newt-2.3.2-driver-kd.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jogamp.jogl\newt\2.3.2\95ef751e091b696ebc4700b5a04891575990122d\newt-2.3.2-driver-linux.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jogamp.jogl\newt\2.3.2\cc363a480a51c59ca3a4a24dc982221a3adb2e81\newt-2.3.2-driver-osx.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jogamp.jogl\newt\2.3.2\5a009f4d9a1730839eefbb0990fdacc35859b48a\newt-2.3.2-driver-win.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jogamp.jogl\newt\2.3.2\c975b00340f112cb8fbbe35bead078f3e64f5a8c\newt-2.3.2-driver-x11.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jogamp.jogl\newt\2.3.2\f05e8b11b0f7ba31a75033d9b40da603c449635\newt-2.3.2-natives-android-aarch64.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jogamp.jogl\newt\2.3.2\7b425742f16722273c189f5f860f212a01b3b462\newt-2.3.2-natives-android-armv6.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jogamp.jogl\newt\2.3.2\24007dc5205f4f9773198d1be5f7013a8b6a2b96\newt-2.3.2-natives-linux-amd64.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jogamp.jogl\newt\2.3.2\f25e0ab0de2dc29d8b16740ff9ae9e52e503bec0\newt-2.3.2-natives-linux-armv6.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jogamp.jogl\newt\2.3.2\e944b80304cda285686fad84963af27e0746b911\newt-2.3.2-natives-linux-armv6hf.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jogamp.jogl\newt\2.3.2\8e2017dd73e68ae1753f0724e0489d835f791946\newt-2.3.2-natives-linux-i586.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jogamp.jogl\newt\2.3.2\eb1257f13f3b411dc83db05ebeb21d44767eaed6\newt-2.3.2-natives-macosx-universal.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jogamp.jogl\newt\2.3.2\5ec2a841e5469e21dd36f3d92365afaad86ade3b\newt-2.3.2-natives-solaris-amd64.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jogamp.jogl\newt\2.3.2\87b54f8bfc1e5190418aaaa6a042473f4f556b15\newt-2.3.2-natives-solaris-i586.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jogamp.jogl\newt\2.3.2\345a309326786646a4b288824c285331496ccfbe\newt-2.3.2-natives-windows-amd64.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jogamp.jogl\newt\2.3.2\e25eae0a0af4c9881b1f105239eb1a11ba8ff062\newt-2.3.2-natives-windows-i586.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jogamp.jogl\nativewindow\2.3.2\c4e73108a1ccb49110516be8b63d44cf07f0f26b\nativewindow-2.3.2.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jogamp.jogl\nativewindow\2.3.2\9eeb70fd34c7c86e586ec02f22eaaf8074ddbcb7\nativewindow-2.3.2-os-win.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jogamp.jogl\nativewindow\2.3.2\bac1ceae906c7a80ad37b42f917ecff289c959d9\nativewindow-2.3.2-os-osx.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jogamp.jogl\nativewindow\2.3.2\a75599e783ff6cbee68e60f80f00113b5e95919f\nativewindow-2.3.2-os-x11.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jogamp.jogl\nativewindow\2.3.2\b3f9623ef71eadfafce4c70f485e3a93dfe7abdf\nativewindow-2.3.2-natives-android-aarch64.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jogamp.jogl\nativewindow\2.3.2\c2003f72ca3de3f34e4920dc2c50b83a094959b9\nativewindow-2.3.2-natives-android-armv6.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jogamp.jogl\nativewindow\2.3.2\fe23dbb106657ac76f7c981e5357c294623b9f8f\nativewindow-2.3.2-natives-linux-amd64.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jogamp.jogl\nativewindow\2.3.2\3ce179989908a51aec7799dfab4841685e6350f6\nativewindow-2.3.2-natives-linux-armv6.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jogamp.jogl\nativewindow\2.3.2\e959e10219f023c27bd4e5582f626e8874825820\nativewindow-2.3.2-natives-linux-armv6hf.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jogamp.jogl\nativewindow\2.3.2\4f556326a5d174a31c9af30127f39fd0c876316b\nativewindow-2.3.2-natives-linux-i586.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jogamp.jogl\nativewindow\2.3.2\c6bfd67b0ac217a403f73894bacc7044059c2a0c\nativewindow-2.3.2-natives-macosx-universal.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jogamp.jogl\nativewindow\2.3.2\63d814027e5f2a1aeb1e9672ec14bc781b8a9843\nativewindow-2.3.2-natives-solaris-amd64.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jogamp.jogl\nativewindow\2.3.2\b887f303070cd0c87a27feabcf344fef9666af66\nativewindow-2.3.2-natives-solaris-i586.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jogamp.jogl\nativewindow\2.3.2\1ec8ecfe1a35a8c50fe36708875c93a9664f24e\nativewindow-2.3.2-natives-windows-amd64.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jogamp.jogl\nativewindow\2.3.2\fda8e3b58cd05acb6bae87966710b7633283704a\nativewindow-2.3.2-natives-windows-i586.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.jetbrains.kotlin\kotlin-stdlib-common\1.5.0\4080d69efca5e39e9b4972f125e40f1607bd6460\kotlin-stdlib-common-1.5.0.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.nytimes.android\cache\2.0.2\dd9712ca1fffcb2d5dfbe2878c1b788be9bc7d76\cache-2.0.2.jar;C:\Users\myusr\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.code.findbugs\jsr305\3.0.1\f7be08ec23c21485b9b5a1cf1654c2ec8c58168d\jsr305-3.0.1.jar)
    at processing.opengl.PSurfaceJOGL$2.run(PSurfaceJOGL.java:408)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

Comment: In case that you have a gradle file already, you will need to run `gradle build .` in your local folder via command line. Then you will be able to use the app

Comment: @GabrielDonada thanks for the suggestion. Build was successful but still getting the error.

Comment: Check [this tutorial](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/setting-up-jni-development-in-gradle-project.html) about how to load and use native libraries via Gradle.